# Why the initial loading state is set to true while using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm confused why the `isLoading` flag is set to **true** in the initial state. Isn't it supposed to be **false** initially? Consider this simple example:

```js
const SearchCharity = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [themes, setThemes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchThemes = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true)

        const result = await axios.get(url)
        setThemes(result.data.themes.theme)

        setIsLoading(false)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    fetchThemes()
  }, [])

  return (
      {
        isLoading ? <h1>Loading......</h1> : <h1>Display Content</h1>
      }
    )

export default SearchCharity
```

Another thing it, if we set it to `true` or `false` initially in the above code, the `useEffect` still runs the same and the result on the screen will also be the same. So, why `true`? Is this some sort of standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value you pass when initializing state is up to you.

If you want it to be initialized as true you pass true like this.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
```

If you want you can also pass false and it will be initialized as false

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [themes, setThemes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchThemes = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(url)
        setThemes(result.data.themes.theme)

        setIsLoading(false)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    fetchThemes()
  }, [])

  return (
      {
        isLoading ? <h1>Loading......</h1> : <h1>Display Content</h1>
      }
    )

export default SearchCharity
```

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the reason that you did set this initial value yourself :)

Most certainly you copied that code from somewhere and the reason the `isLoading`'s initial state is set to `true` is that your whole component actually is in such state initially and then you set it to false after fetched data is ready.

Comment: No, it was `false`, I just changed it to ask a general question here. I set `isLoading` to false always but I see people always setting it to `true`. Setting it to `true` initially doesn't make sense. When fetching hasn't even begun, how could we set it to `true`? Isn't it should be `false-> true-> false`?

Comment: Actually you're wrong in this case (you'd be right if you rendered your component first and then fetched data i.e. on button click). The hook you used is nothing else but componentDidMount(), so if you fetch the data on mounting it really doesn't make any difference whether you set the initial state to false or set it to false in your hook.